# Dynamic include and function call of multiple Python modules

Tags: python

## Introduction

Hi! I'm working on a Python project where I'm trying to load any number of py-files from a directory and then conditionally call a function if it exists. I'm able to iterate over all py-files in a directory and include them, but the problem arise when I'm trying to act upon these modules.

The script should:

- List an inventory of py-files in folder "modules"
- Import all these files into a list/dictionary/array/object of modules.
- Conditionally call specific functions IF said function could be found.

We don't know how many py-files are in the folder and we also don't know which have the correct function.

## Installation

- OS: Microsoft Windows 11
- Python: 3.10.4

## Folder Structure

- /main.py
- /modules/one.py
- /modules/two.py
- /modules/three.py
- /modules/imposter.txt

## Project Files

### main.py

```
# Import the ability to list files and directories.
import glob
import os.path

# Load a list of py-files from the modules-directory.
files = map(os.path.basename, glob.glob("modules/*.py"))

# Initialize an empty dictionary of imported modules with a dynamic length.
modules = {}

# Iterate through all the files...
for file in files:
    print("Importing " + file)
    modules[file] = __import__("modules", globals(), locals(), [file], 0)
```

### modules/one.py

```
print("one.py says hi!")

sayBye = "foo"
```

### modules/two.py

```
print("two.py says hello!")

def sayBye():
    print("two.py says bye!")
```

### modules/three.py

```
print("three.py says hello!")
```

## Output

The output so far in the project is:

```
>python main.py
Importing one.py
one.py says hello!
Importing two.py
two.py says hello!
Importing three.py
three.py says hello!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Ok, so far so good. The files are loading. Now, I want to implement functionality to check if any of the files contain a function "sayBye" and if it does; call it.

## Problem

### main.py

Added to the end of the file:

```
print("--")

for module in modules:
    if "sayBye" in dir(module):
        if callable(getattr(module, "sayBye")):
            module.sayBye()
        else:
            print("sayBye is not a function.")
    else:
        print("sayBye could not be found.")
```

#### Expected Result

```
>python main.py
Importing one.py
one.py says hello!
Importing two.py
two.py says hello!
Importing three.py
three.py says hello!
--
sayBye is not a function.
two.py says bye!
sayBye could not be found.
Press any key to containue . . .
```

#### Actual Result

```
>python main.py
Importing one.py
one.py says hello!
Importing two.py
two.py says hello!
Importing three.py
three.py says hello!
--
sayBye could not be found.
sayBye could not be found.
sayBye could not be found.
Press any key to containue . . .
```

It seems like `module` is either invalid or the functionality to validate the function is fault.
Looking forward for feedback. Cheers!

Comment: Why don't you simply call your function in a `try... except` block?

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille Good idea. Not sure as I want the function declaration to be entirely optional. The modules CAN, but does not have to, declare the function. But if they do, it will be called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`modules` is a dictionary.  The key is the filename, the value is the module.  When you say

```
for module in modules:
```

you are enumerating over the keys -- the filenames.  What you want is:

```
for module in modules.values():
```

#### Followup

The other problem is that your import module is essentially doing

```
import modules
```

As a result, all of them come in with the same name.  You end up with three references to the same module object.  You need to use the proper name, which would be `modules/one`, etc:

```
# Iterate through all the files...
for file in files:
    base = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    print("Importing",file,"as",base)
    modules[file] = __import__("modules."+base, globals(), locals(), [file], 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of this. I've implemented your answer, but the reults are still the same. Python can't find function "sayBye" in any of the modules.

Comment: That's because you are importing all three modules with the name `"modules"`.  Each one overrides the previous ones.  I'll modify the answer to solve this.